# Too less vs too little

Tags: comparatives, countable-nouns

Consider these two sentences:

1. One week is too little to observe a measurable weight loss.
2. One week is too less to observe a measurable weight loss.

When I uttered (2) in casual speech, my friend corrected it to (1). I agreed: (1) sounded better. But is (2) grammatically incorrect?

Does thinking of "One week" as an uncountable quantity (time period) make a difference?

Comment: **Too + adjective** (too late/too much/too little) *less* is the comparative of the adjective *little* when referring to quantity. That is to say: little --> less ---> the least. We cannot say "too smaller" but we do say "too small".

Comment: I think you neglected to say this means #2 is incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

The intensifier  ***too*** cannot be used with comparative and superlative forms. *Less* is the comparative of *little* (irregular: little, less, the least) and therefore we cannot use it with *too*. You can say: ***much*** less, but that has a different meaning.

Answer (score 3):

Too less is actually a very typical non-native mistake. Not sure of the rules behind it but "Too less" just doesn't work no matter where you use it.

Answer (score 0):

No one uses

*"is too less to observe"*

at Google Books.

There are 8 instances of

*"is **too little** to observe"*

which makes it quite possible, and it is:

> Review of the Electrical Communication Laboratory 1964 - ‎Snippet view
>
> However, as is clear from Table 6, the content of vinyl chloride **is
>   too little to observe** the change of stereoregularity.

This is of course in some grammar books (see "little" vs "less").